# How do I lookup a polymer by its structure?

Tags: polymers

This is more of a meta-chemistry question, but, here goes...

Given the structure of a polymer, how can I search online for which polymer it is?

Specifically, I have an image like this:

[image]

I'd also like to know which polymer specifically this is, but also a method for figuring this out in the future by myself :)

Comment: A polymer is generally an organic compound with a base component of repeating units- generally 1000's of units such as CH2 for polyethylene. Nothing repeats in this compound so its not a polymer. An oligomer is like a polymer but has far smaller numbers of repeating units. A polymer as a material is a plastic- it have engineering value whereas an oligiomer behaves like a chemical.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like bilirubin, from hemoglobin catabolized in the liver  Monomer, dimer..tetramer...oligomer...polymer...high polymer.  It is a tetrapyrrole, not even an oligomer.